# Does each particle have its own space-time field?

Tags: particle-physics, spacetime, field-theory

I have seen questions here asking about each particle having its own corresponding field, (Higgs particle to Higgs field, and others) and the answer seems to be yes but does that mean that it also has its own space-time field, is that just an intrinsic nature of all fields or is space-time its own unique field?

Comment: In a relativistic field model, particle number isn’t conserved.  So thinking of it as “particles have associated fields” isn’t particularly helpful. Closer to “reality” would be fields exist upon the background of spacetime, and in different frames of reference can appear to have different levels of excitation that observers in different frames will not agree upon.  All will agree there’s a field, though.

Comment: Consider to define what you mean by 'spacetime field'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacetime isn’t a field. Spacetime is the arena where quantum fields live and interact. Each kind of elementary particle has a field, with values at every point in spacetime. For example, there is only one universal electron field, which fills spacetime, and all electrons and positrons are its quanta. The various quantum fields (for quarks, charged leptons, neutrinos, photons, weak bosons, gluons, and Higgs) all exist in the same spacetime.